# Cucumber not storing session past first page view

Tags: session, cucumber, capybara

I am going through this situation: [Rails, Cucumber, Capybara: session is not persisted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144724/rails-cucumber-capybara-session-is-not-persisted)

There wasn't a chosen answer on that page, and each posted answer didn't work for me, so I will try to expand on the problem a bit.  Cucumber/Capybara tends to only keep the session around for one page view.  If you try traversing past the first page, you immediately get redirected to the login page.  The session doesn't persist and Capybara is forced to log out.

I visited this article: http://blog.ardes.com/2010/4/28/capybara-and-rack-test-sessions-and-http-methods
and have found no luck as my paths were already starting with forward slashes.

Anyone have any 2 cents about this issue?  Thanks!