# How do I set up a session value in Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, shopify

I am developing an app for Shopify and I want to do integration testing.

I need to be able to store some values in the session variable, so that authentication works.

How could I do that?

I use Capybara and Capybara-webkit.

Comment: In integration testing, you should log users from the login forms.

Comment: That won't work. The key issue is that I am using an external authentication system: Shopify. So Shopify is configured to return a successful log-in to a specific URL. Do see the problem? That URL can't be localhost. That's why I need to fake the log in process, even if I am in Integration testing

Comment: how can i use the same for cucumber in shopify app?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just found [rack_session_access](https://github.com/railsware/rack_session_access) gem and working as a charm.

Comment: @fguillen how can i use the same for cucumber in shopify app?

Answer (score 33):

The accepted answer suggests [rack_session_access](https://github.com/railsware/rack_session_access).  It works by inserting middleware controllers to edit and update the session state, then has capybara visit that page and submit a form with the session data.  Very ingenious! But unnecessary if you are using Warden (directly or through Devise).

Warden has a hook [on_next_request](https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki/Testing) that gives access to the warden mechanism, which can be used to set session keys directly. I threw this together to bundle it up in rspec:

Create `spec/support/inject_session.rb`:

```
module InjectSession
  include Warden::Test::Helpers

  def inject_session(hash)
    Warden.on_next_request do |proxy|
      hash.each do |key, value|
        proxy.raw_session[key] = value
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In `spec/spec_helper.rb` include the module in feature specs:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.include InjectSession, :type => :feature
end
```

Then sample use in a spec might be:

```
   inject_session :magic => 'pixie dust', :color => 'pink' 
   visit shopping_cart_path
   page.should be_all_sparkly_and_pink # or whatever
```

Comment: @YossiShasho in what way does it not work? it seems to work fine for me, currently with devise 3.2.4 and warden 1.2.3

Comment: I honestly don't remember what went wrong, but i didn't try too hard to resolve it. Just went ahead with the `rack_session_access ` gem suggested above, which worked fine.

Comment: I would have preferred this solution very much. Did not work unfortunately so I also switched to rack_session_access (Ruby 2.2, Rails 4.2)

Comment: This also works for me on Rails 4.2, Devise 3.4.1 etc.

Comment: Man you make may day better! Working here Devise 4.5.0 and Rails 5.2.1. Thank you! <3

Comment: I just wanted to mention that we need to ask Rails (at least in Rails > 6) to autoload this new folder. We can do this by adding this line in the `rails_helper.rb`:

`Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require(f) }`

Answer (score 4):

As the comment by apneadiving recommends, you should fill the form out "directly" using capybara.  Testing using Cucumber might look like this for filling in a login form for authentication (from the [Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) github page):

```
When /I sign in/ do
  within("#session") do
    fill_in 'Login', :with => 'user@example.com'
    fill_in 'Password', :with => 'password'
  end
  click_link 'Sign in'
  ...
end
```

If you trying to do something different or are having trouble with the normal login process, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144724/rails-cucumber-capybara-session-is-not-persisted) SO question may help.

Comment: That won't work. The key issue is that I am using an external authentication system: Shopify. So Shopify is configured to return a successful log-in to a specific URL. Do see the problem? That URL can't be localhost. That's why I need to fake the log in process, even if I am in Integration testing.

Comment: @Nerian see if you can use https://github.com/myronmarston/vcr to record that external request to your local environment, then you can use this method.

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like VCR or webmock to stub out the call to the external http resource.

Answer (score 3):

I fear I bring bad news, but from Capybara's documentation:

> Access to session and request is not possible from the test, Access to
>   response is limited.

So you won't be able to test as you expect.

---

Just thinking:  it would be acceptable that you insert some conditional statement in your controller for test purpose.:

```
 session[:foo] = User.first.id if Rails.env.test?
```

A better option would be to monkey patch your controller only for your integration tests.

Comment: This is possible, but feels like a code smell - injecting test code into your production application? It would be preferable to re-write your tests, if you can.